# CSS - adding padding to list items not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have an un-ordered list like so:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">40' Singles</li>
        <li>46' Singles</li>
        <li>50' Singles</li>
        <li>Custom Lots</li>
</ul>
```

each list item is 50% in width, are floating left and have a background-color:

```
ul li {
 float: left; width: 50%; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); 
}
```

Looks okay, so far, I have two list items per a line which is what I want, now I am trying to add padding to each list item so the background-colors are not touching..I have tried adding a padding of 20px and that did not work, added the padding, but now my list items are on their own line, I also tried with a margin of 20px, same result, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Voting to reopen because the duplicate answer only gets part way to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `box-sizing: border-box` to your `li` styles. The reason, is padding is not included in the width by default.

```css
ul.calc li {
  float: left;
  width: calc( 50% - 20px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.background-clip li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="calc">
  <li class="active">40' Singles</li>
  <li>46' Singles</li>
  <li>50' Singles</li>
  <li>Custom Lots</li>
</ul>

<ul class="background-clip">
  <li class="active">40' Singles</li>
  <li>46' Singles</li>
  <li>50' Singles</li>
  <li>Custom Lots</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I did that but the background-colours are still touching

Comment: however they are no longer on their own line, which is good, but yea the background-colors are still touching...how would I get spacing?

Comment: Updated answer. Use `calc()` on width and add margin.

Comment: @user979331 or add `background-clip:content-box` and no need to add margin or change the width

Comment: @TemaniAfif That works as well, but then the padding bg-color will disappear. I added it as another example.

Comment: @user979331 can you mark this as the accepted answer since your question was reopened? Thanks!